# swap the keys and values in a dictionary by storing the user input in dic

Tags: python-3.x

First the input should be dic length consider 3. then the input to a dic is keys and values separated by spaces i,e
"A 1
B 2
C 1"
now dic={A:1, B:2, C:1}
At first the keys and values and should be swapped, and if there are same keys and there values should be merged in a list and assigned to the same key as shown below.(these program should work for any length of dictionary)

the output should be dicout={1:['A','C'], 2:B}.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Define:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_dict(s):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    xs = s.split(" ")

    for k, v in zip(xs[1::2], xs[::2]):
        d[k].append(v)

    for k, v in d.items():
        if len(v) == 1:
            d[k] = v[0]

    return dict(d)
```

**Example usage:**

```
>>> make_dict("A 1 B 2 C 1")
{'1': ['A', 'C'], '2': 'B'}
```